# IIS 6 Performance monitor

Tags: .net, iis-7, iis-6, performance-monitor

I want to get the active user sessions for a particular website.

I am using Performance Monitor to get the current active sessions of an IIS6 website.

The active session counter gives me the session instances and hence the active session count for a particular website when on **IIS 7 - windows server 2008 r2** but when I try the same on an **IIS6 - windows server 2003 server**, the performance counter doesn't show any session instances.

Any idea?